# IntelliJ checkstyle plugin reformat

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I followed the step [add checkstyle](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61520#comment=27-1292600)

Here are the specific steps:
Setup Steps

1. Go to IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Browse repositories.
2. Search for and Install the "Checkstyle-IDEA" plugin, restart IntelliJ.
3. Go to IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Other Settings -> Checkstyle.
4. Under "Configuration File" click "+" and name the description "Customized Checkstyle".
5. Click on "Use a checkstyle file accessible via HTTP" and "ignore invalid certificates".
6. For the URL use: https://drive-xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com/view/xxxxx/checkstyle-rules.xml (corporate website) click "Next" and then click "Finish".
7. Click on the checkbox for "Customized Checkstyle", click "Apply" and "OK".

And I can run in real-time checkstyle to my code. However, when I **reformat** the code, the formatted code does not match the checkstyle, could you please let me know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Code formatting is a separate thing from checkstyle. But you can convert checkstyle to a IDEA's code formatting: Settings -> File | Settings | Editor | Code Style and on the left hand side of the **Scheme** there is cog, click on it, then Import Scheme -> CheckStyle Configuration:

[image: screenshot]

Note that you will need to download the checkstyle xml config file.

Comment: I spent quite some time trying to find this answer, hope it gets more light :)
Thanks, streetturtle

Comment: How is code formatting different then check style ?